# cannot resolve this error: unable to insert NULL in ("NAWFEL". "ORDO_DEP_UUSATEUR". "EMPLOI")

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, postman

I'm developing a user registration form, the problem I get is that when I want to test my web service in postman it shows me the following error in my eclipse console:

```
 2020-06-02 19:50:04.559  WARN 1576 --- [nio-8484-exec-2]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1400, SQLState:
> 23000 2020-06-02 19:50:04.560 ERROR 1576 --- [nio-8484-exec-2]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-01400: impossible
> d'insérer NULL dans ("NAWFEL"."ORDO_DEP_UTILISATEUR"."EMPLOI")
> 
> 2020-06-02 19:50:04.582 ERROR 1576 --- [nio-8484-exec-2]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
> execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
> execute statement] with root cause
> 
> oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01400: impossible d'insérer
> NULL dans ("NAWFEL"."ORDO_DEP_UTILISATEUR"."EMPLOI")
> 
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513)
> ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]     at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461)
> ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]     at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104)
> ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]     at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:550)
> ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]     at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268)
> ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]     at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655)
> ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
```

he tells me that I cannot insert a null value in the job "emploi" column, but I entered the value of the job column in my postman as you can see here:

[image: postman]

this is my entity code :

```
package com.app.habilitation.entity;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="ORDO_DEP_UTILISATEUR")
public class UserEntity {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="IDENTIFIANT")
    private Integer IDENTIFIANT;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOI") 


    private EmploiEntity emploi;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="ENTITE") 

    private EntiteEntity entite;


    @Column(name="LOGIN")
    private String login;


    @Column(name="MOTDEPASSE")
    private String mdp;


    @Column(name="NOM")
    private String nom;

    @Column(name="PRENOM")
    private String prenom;

    @Column(name="CREEPAR")
    private Integer creerpar;

    @Column(name="ANNULEPAR")
    private Integer annulepar;

    @Column(name="STATUT")
    private String statut;

    @Column(name="DATEEFFET")
    private Date dateeffet;


    @Column(name="DATEFIN")
    private Date datefin;

    @Column(name="CREELE")
    private Date creele;

    @Column(name="MOTIFDEDESACTIVATION")
    private String motifdedesactivation;

    @Column(name="ANNULELE")
    private Date annulele;


    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="CONFIRMATIONMOTDEPASSE")
    private String confirmation_mot_de_passe;




    public String getConfirmation_mot_de_passe() {
        return confirmation_mot_de_passe;
    }

    public void setConfirmation_mot_de_passe(String confirmation_mot_de_passe) {
        this.confirmation_mot_de_passe = confirmation_mot_de_passe;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getIDENTIFIANT() {
        return IDENTIFIANT;
    }

    public void setIDENTIFIANT(Integer iDENTIFIANT) {
        IDENTIFIANT = iDENTIFIANT;
    }

    public EmploiEntity getEmploi() {
        return emploi;
    }

    public void setEmploi(EmploiEntity emploi) {
        this.emploi = emploi;
    }



    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getMdp() {
        return mdp;
    }

    public void setMdp(String mdp) {
        this.mdp = mdp;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public Integer getCreerpar() {
        return creerpar;
    }

    public void setCreerpar(Integer creerpar) {
        this.creerpar = creerpar;
    }

    public Integer getAnnulepar() {
        return annulepar;
    }

    public void setAnnulepar(Integer annulepar) {
        this.annulepar = annulepar;
    }

    public String getStatut() {
        return statut;
    }

    public void setStatut(String statut) {
        this.statut = statut;
    }

    public Date getDateeffet() {
        return dateeffet;
    }

    public void setDateeffet(Date dateeffet) {
        this.dateeffet = dateeffet;
    }

    public Date getDatefin() {
        return datefin;
    }

    public void setDatefin(Date datefin) {
        this.datefin = datefin;
    }

    public Date getCreele() {
        return creele;
    }

    public void setCreele(Date creele) {
        this.creele = creele;
    }

    public String getMotifdedesactivation() {
        return motifdedesactivation;
    }

    public void setMotifdedesactivation(String motifdedesactivation) {
        this.motifdedesactivation = motifdedesactivation;
    }

    public Date getAnnulele() {
        return annulele;
    }

    public void setAnnulele(Date annulele) {
        this.annulele = annulele;
    }





    public EntiteEntity getEntite() {
        return entite;
    }

    public void setEntite(EntiteEntity entite) {
        this.entite = entite;
    }









    public UserEntity(EmploiEntity emploi, EntiteEntity entite, String login, String mdp, String nom, String prenom,
            Integer creerpar, Integer annulepar, String statut, Date dateeffet, Date datefin, Date creele,
            String motifdedesactivation, Date annulele, String email, String confirmation_mot_de_passe) {
        this.emploi = emploi;
        this.entite = entite;
        this.login = login;
        this.mdp = mdp;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.creerpar = creerpar;
        this.annulepar = annulepar;
        this.statut = statut;
        this.dateeffet = dateeffet;
        this.datefin = datefin;
        this.creele = creele;
        this.motifdedesactivation = motifdedesactivation;
        this.annulele = annulele;
        this.email = email;
        this.confirmation_mot_de_passe = confirmation_mot_de_passe;
    }

    public UserEntity() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserEntity [IDENTIFIANT=" + IDENTIFIANT + ", emploi=" + emploi + ", entite=" + entite + ", login="
                + login + ", mdp=" + mdp + ", nom=" + nom + ", prenom=" + prenom + ", creerpar=" + creerpar
                + ", annulepar=" + annulepar + ", statut=" + statut + ", dateeffet=" + dateeffet + ", datefin="
                + datefin + ", creele=" + creele + ", motifdedesactivation=" + motifdedesactivation + ", annulele="
                + annulele + ", email=" + email + ", confirmation_mot_de_passe=" + confirmation_mot_de_passe + "]";
    }






}
```

and this is my dao ( i use jpa) :

```
package com.app.habilitation.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.app.habilitation.entity.UserEntity;

public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer> {



}
```

and this is my userService :

```
package com.app.habilitation.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.app.habilitation.entity.UserEntity;

public interface UserService {

    public void save (UserEntity theUser);


}
```

and this is my userServiceImpl :

```
package com.app.habilitation.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.app.habilitation.dao.UserDao;
import com.app.habilitation.entity.UserEntity;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired

    public UserServiceImpl (UserDao theuserDao) {

        userDao = theuserDao;
    }



    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(UserEntity theUser) {

        userDao.save(theUser);

    }



}
```

and this is my controller :

```
package com.app.habilitation.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.app.habilitation.entity.UserEntity;
import com.app.habilitation.service.UserService;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
//@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController (UserService theuserService) {
        userService=theuserService;
    }


    @GetMapping("/")
    public String login() {
        return "authenticaated succesfully";
    }


    @GetMapping("/getUsers") 
    public String getUsers() {
        return "users";
    }


    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public UserEntity addUser (@RequestBody UserEntity theUser) {

        System.out.println("test");
        userService.save(theUser);

        return theUser;
    }
}
```

and this is my table user (i use oracle 10g) :

[image: table in oracle 10g]

can someone help me please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to send them as an objects like this

```
{
   "emploi":{"IDENTIFIANT":1}
    // and so on for any object
}
```

Comment: Okay, you can put a breakpoint in the controller and see if the object is there or not

Comment: great, then try to debug on the controller level and see if the object is binded or not. as a first step

Comment: how can i do that? sorry if this is a stupid question but i am still just a beginner :( can you show me how to debug and find the error please? (i use eclipse i click on run as debug but i don't know not what to do next)

Comment: thank you very much for sharing this video with me, I made a breakpoint in the return of my addUser method which is in my controller and when I launch my request from postman the debuggin mode takes me to this method: static void exitCurrentThread() {
  throw new SilentExitException();
 } which is in another named class: SilentExitExceptionHandler

Comment: you are welcome my friend,  skip this one by clicking the play |> button, after that send the request from postman and then you will find that you are inside your class

Comment: I do not see the button play i just see the button "resume", "terminate", "step into", "step over, "step return", "drop to frame", "use step filters"

Comment: (i use eclipse)

Comment: ok I clicked on the  resume button and i send the request from postman , and now what do I have to do ?

Comment: you open your ide 'eclipse' you will find that you are stoped at the breakpoint that you added later, hover on '@RequestBody UserEntity theUser' and see the values inside

Comment: I see that all values are null :(

Comment: do you mind having a zoom call?, I assume that you are speaking Arabic. I'm open to help.

Comment: yes i speak arabic and french but english no i just use google translation to speak here, it doesn't bother that we speak in arabic or french and not english?

Comment: I mean having a call using zoom. if that is convenient with you Hesham Osman is inviting you to a scheduled Zoom meeting.

Topic: Hesham Osman's Personal Meeting Room

Join Zoom Meeting
https://cegedim.zoom.us/j/2756160775

Comment: join using this link